# Cannot select the proper site-packages folder using virtualenv

Tags: python

I see a lot of help on the internet about finding out where the site-packages that you're using is located but not information about how to fix the problem if you're using an undesirable site-package folder.  I'm using virtualenv and I would think that if I input in command line:

```
cd /users/me/documents/codes/venv3/bin && source activate && cd /users/me/documents/pcode/
```

that I would use the site-package folder located in venv3 but that is not the case.  Note: I realize venv and virtualenv are different things but I made the mistake of calling the folder venv even though I'm using virtualenv

When I input:

```
python -m site --user-site
```

I get:

```
/Users/me/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages
```

I want it to be

```
/users/me/documents/codes/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

What am I doing wrong?

######UPDATE

here is the full output of

```
python -m site

sys.path = [
    '/Users/kylefoley/Documents/pcode',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/kylefoley/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aeosa',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/kylefoley/Library/Python/3.8' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/kylefoley/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

I would think that the output should be:

USER_SITE: users/me/documents/codes/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages

ENABLE_USER_SITE: False

Am I right.  If so, how do I get it that way?

Also, to answer your other question, I get (venv3) when I activate the virtualenv.

I should also point out that I'm working on this problem because I'm getting module not found errors.

Comment: You appear to be activating the virtual environment in an unusual way. After you run this command, does it show anything in your shell's prompt? Usually it will add an `(env)` to the prompt if the activation worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When I activate my virtual environment, I get a similar output to you when I run `python -m site --user-site`. However, this is the correct behaviour for a virtual environment.

Here's the full output of `python -m site`:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/me/Source/thing',
    '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
    '/home/me/Source/thing/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/me/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/me/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

Although the `USER_SITE` is set, it is disabled (`ENABLE_USER_SITE: False`), meaning that any imported files will be loaded from the virtual environment (the last element on the path variable).

I use `venv` rather than `virtualenv` though, so it could be worthwhile double checking that your output is the same.

Comment: see update.....

Answer (score -2):

I used to backup my files with google cloud.  I got rid of it but it was still affecting some of my files.  That working environment was one of them.  I decided to simply build a new working environment from scratch and all of the problems went away.